# Magento 2 search returns 1 product only

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch

I have a problem in my store, the search returns only 1 product shows, I already did the re-index and cleared the cache.

The products also have stock and visibility for catalog and search.

http://lambegato.com.br/

Test Product: Banqueta

Comment: Check the store view of the products also

Comment: @MGento Which setting do I recommend checking?